# How to protect a video streaming url by hiding or masking it?

Tags: html, video-streaming, azure-media-services

I need to add a video player to my website that will play content from video streaming (YouTube Live, Azure Media Services or any streaming services from a hosting company).

The player will be visible only to authenticated users, but as the streaming URL won't change, I needed to hide it from the user (maybe using DNS configuration in my domain or something else).

Do you know a way to protect the streaming URL?

Comment: Are you just trying to obfuscate it so it's not easy to see with a view-source, or do you truly want to hide it completely (from the browser dev tools, for example)?

Comment: I think most of my target users don't know how to use developer tools and the streaming will be available just for 6 days. I just want to obfuscate the url so people that don't have signed up to my Web seminar won't be able to watch it.

Comment: I assume server-side, since client-side defeats the purpose. Hex or Base64 encode it? Note preventing people from watching a public YouTube video who haven't signed up for your service is a different story. As in, you cannot stop them. At that point, you may need to make a URL on your site that authenticates a user and then does a 301 to YouTube.

Comment: You mean encoding the streaming url? It can be a non listed YouTube video or a streaming server I'd pay for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the requirement that you do not want people to see the video even if they have gotten the URL (“so people that don't have signed up to my Web seminar won't be able to watch it”), and given that the player is available only to authenticated users, I have a suggestion:

1. Create a unique URL at your domain for each video stream.
2. When a user hits the URL of the stream, do the following:

   1. Use your authentication logic to see if the user has permission.
   2. If the user has permission, use a 301 or pass the stream through to the player.
   3. If the user does not have permission, redirect the user to the login page (or whatever).
3. Repeat.

From experience, once you get much beyond that level of complexity you need to start looking at services that do this as their business model. Otherwise you run the risk of falling into the rabbit hole.

The caveat here is that once the user has the stream, a motivated person can still identify the source URL and do whatever with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect your content, you have to encrypt it and decrypt on a fly for authenticated users. Content key for decryption might be associated to specific media content and have expiration. In this case even users who know the streaming uri, have to obtain content key for decryption. You can use clear key encryption or DRM services to archive this scenario. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/content-protection/ - contains overview of content protection options in Azure Media Services. 
Nothing stops user to open any browser dev tool and copy destination uri if you just masking url by providing redirect.